# Working on a baseball simulator for a class and I can't quite figure out how to push a runner that is on 1st base to second after a single is hit

Tags: java

```
public boolean runnerOnBase(int i) {
      if (basesRun == i)
      {
          return true;
      }
      return false;
  }
```

this is the boolean I have that for now just puts a runner on the base swung without any pushes

```
public String getBases()
  {
    return (runnerOnBase(1) ? "X" : "o") + (runnerOnBase(2) ? "X" : "o")
        + (runnerOnBase(3) ? "X" : "o");
  }
```

the following method can't be changed and uses an int as a parameter that checks the base corresponding to the number for a runner.

```
 public int hit(int i)
  {
      if ((i >= 15) && (i < 150))
      {
          basesRun = 1;
      }
      else if ((i >= 150) && (i < 200))
      {
          basesRun = 2;
      }
      else if ((i >= 200) && (i < 250))
      {
          basesRun = 3;
      }
      else if (i >= 250)
      {
          basesRun = 4;
      }
```

this is my code that determines the amount of bases run per distance given

I'm honestly just very lost

Comment: If there is only one variable, `basesRun`, how can two or three runners be on base? The first method could be simplified to `return basesRun == i;` but first you have to think about how you are tracking base runners.